# Motivic integrals and linear equivalence

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

There are many expository accounts of Kontsevich's theory of motivic integration, and his theorem on birational Calabi-Yau varieties.  However, one technical point that I am confused about is whether the integral $$\int_{{\rm Arc}(X)} \mathbb L^{-{\rm ord} D}$$  only depends on the divisor $D$ up to linear equivalence.  I think that this is implicitly assumed in most expositions, but it is not obvious to me.   Is there an reference where this dependence is treated explicitly,  or a simple argument for why the integral only depends on the equivalence class of $D$?

Answer (score 2):

The "implicit assumption" is not actually being used, and I do not think that the integral is independent of the choice of divisor.

Instead the unstated fact is the following:  let $X \leftarrow^f Z \rightarrow^g Y$ be a diagram of birational morphisms.  If $f^* \omega_X \cong g^* \omega_Y$  then there is an *equality*  of relative canonical divisors $K_{f} = K_{g}$.